# Playa hidden field with safecracker not (completely?) creating relationships

Tags: safecracker, playa

Going crazy here - I can't get any results to display in exp:playa:parents when specifying a particular channel. If I don't include the channel= parameter I get a result from another channel which is correct, but when specifying the channel I want I get no results, despite being able to see in the CP that they are related.

No custom statuses involved for either parent or child channel. Playa 4.3.3 and EE 2.5.5 I've tried specifying the entry_id for a particular entry I want the parents of and still get nothing. What could be going wrong?

Edit: Ok, I've figured out it's only for parent entries that are created with safecracker. In the CP, if I open an entry created with safecracker and save it, the entry appears in the list of parents. So it's a playa/safecracker issue.

Edit 2: Hi Lisa! Thanks for your help. This has changed so much I've completely changed the title. Important thing I should have mentioned: I'm using the playa as a hidden field method in safecracker as described here: https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/sending_playa_field_value_hidden_in_safecracker

So my field in safecracker looks like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cm_community[selections][]" value="{exp:url_title_to_entry_id url_title='{segment_3}'}">
```

where I'm using a plugin to get the entry id from a urltitle in the url.

When I go into the CP, the correct entry is selected in the Playa field, which is why I thought the relationships were being created but I don't think they are. If I just open the entry and save it I see this in the 'View Entry' screen:

```
[18026] [double-bay] Double Bay
```

Which is the entry id, url title and Title of the entry I assigned in the Playa field, and also makes me think the relationship exists.

However if I open the entry in the CP, use the Playa select input to choose that entry (that already appears to be chosen) and save, the relationship is 'properly' created and I can see it on the front end.

I'll paste my template code as well though I don't think that's the issue:

```
{exp:playa:parents channel="community_messages" field="cm_community" limit="1"}

    {if no_parents}<p>No messages.</p>{/if}

    <div class="cm">

        <h2>{title}</h2>

        {cm_message}

    </div>

{/exp:playa:parents}
```

Edit: Adding full safecracker code

```
{exp:safecracker channel="community_messages" return="communities/{segment_2}/messages/" author_only="yes" include_jquery="no"}

<label for="title">Message Title</label>
<input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" maxlength="100">

<label for="cm_message">Message Content</label>
{field:cm_message}

{if '{segment_4}'!='edit'}
<input type="hidden" name="cm_community[selections][]" value="{exp:url_title_to_entry_id url_title='{segment_2}'}">
{/if}

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post">

{/exp:safecracker}
```

Comment: Future entry date, or expired entry?

Comment: Nope, no future or expired entries.

Comment: Hey BenB - so this happens only when you submit the data using a Safecracker form?  Can you add your template code to your original post, please? Also, when you load that template in the front-end and view your debug console, are there any JS errors?  Thank you!

Comment: When you add in that code, could you also include your output code? Thank you! I'm having some trouble reproducing this so knowing a lot more about your setup and template code would help a lot.

Comment: Hi Lisa, just updated the question substantially. I am getting this JS error on the safecracker page, not sure if related: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'ee_filebrowser'

Comment: Can you post your entire Safecracker code?  Reducing it to the minimum where you see the problem would help out.  Thank you!

Comment: Just added the code - it's a very minimal form.

Comment: Ben - I'd like to back up; I know you have a particular goal here, but I want to make sure Playa is behaving along the way.  Can you try using the {field:field_name} variable for Playa and test if things work that way?  If so, we'll move on to your hidden field.  If not... troubleshooting. ;) Thank you!

Comment: Hi Lisa, yep it works fine if I use the {field:field_name} format.

Comment: Hey Ben - sorry that I didn't come back to this!  I am curious, if you view the form using {field:field_name} and take that source and paste it into your template - can you get it to work that way as a hidden field?